# How can I post several images from this Controller?

Tags: php, laravel

## Basic Information

I'm developing a simple Web Application that it can post photo using Laravel.

## My Question

I want to create several image post form using  another variable.

How can I make work my Controllers using  another variable?

## My Codes

`routes/web.php`

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('login'); 

Route::group(['middleweare' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'StoriesController@index');
    Route::post('/', 'StoriesController@store');
    Route::get('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@add');
    Route::post('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@uplaod');
});

Route::group(['middleweare' => 'auth','name'=>'profile'], function () {
    Route::get('/profile/edit', 'ProfileController@edit');
    Route::get('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@add');
    Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@store');
    Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@upload');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();
```

`app/Http/Controllers/StoriesController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Story;
use Auth;
use App\Posts;
use App\History;
use App\Attachment;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Storage;

class StoriesController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('auth');
    }

  public function index(Request $request)
      {
        
        $images = Attachment::all();

      
        return view('stories.index2', compact('images'));
      }

  public function add()
    {
      return view('stories.create2');
    }


  public function store(Request $request)
  {
  
    $d = new \DateTime();
    $d->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'));
    $dir = $d->format('Y/m');
    $path = sprintf('public/images/%s', $dir);

 
    $data = $request->except('_token');

    foreach ($data['images'] as $k => $v) {

      $filename = '';


      $attachments = Attachment::take(1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

      foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        
        $filename = $attachment->id + 1 . '_' . $v->getClientOriginalName();
      }
      unset($attachment);

      if ($filename == false) {
        $filename = 1 . '_' . $v->getClientOriginalName();
      }

      $v->storeAs($path, $filename);

      $attachment_data = [
        'path' => sprintf('images/%s/', $dir),
        'name' => $filename
      ];
      
      $a = new Attachment();
      $a->fill($attachment_data)->save();
    }

    unset($k, $v);

    return redirect('/');
  }

  
  public function upload(Request $request)
    {
      dd($request->all());
      $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => [
          'required',
          'file',
          'image',
          'mimes:jpeg,png',
        ]
      ]);

      if ($request->file('file')->isValid([])) {
        $path = $request->file->store('public');
        return view('stories.index2')->with('filename', basename($path));
      } else {
        return redirect('/')
          ->back()
          ->withInput()
          ->withErrors();
      }
    }
}
```

I made a profile image post form, and general image post form.
And I want to view those image on same page.